# filter data by selecting multiple or single checkbox and without selecting it should show all results in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, filter

I want to add filter in my code in anguarjs, it should filter data when i'll select any one check box or multiple check box, and if didn't select any check box it should show all the results without filtering..
here what I did, but the problem is its only display data when i select one or multiple check box, but i want it should show data without filtering too..

```
    var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.alljobs  =  [{
    "id": "1",
    "company_id": "1",
    "job_title": "Full Stack ngularJs Developer",
    "descr": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed quis magna non arcu cursus pharetra et posuere est. Curabitur nibh neque, euismod eget felis sed, gravida cursus risus. Praesent mattis rutrum posuere. Integer eget odio mauris. Fusce luctus, ex nec lobortis vestibulum, arcu arcu suscipit magna, at gravida erat lorem sit amet est. Duis eget ante non ante blandit scelerisque vel et nunc. Nullam a nisl tincidunt, congue risus in, scelerisque ipsum. Phasellus fermentum, nibh id convallis varius, orci urna feugiat velit, in imperdiet dolor nulla non velit. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Phasellus vel quam ex. Morbi a nibh efficitur, viverra odio eget, feugiat massa. Etiam rhoncus, metus at lobortis dapibus, quam mi auctor odio, a vestibulum ante justo pellentesque urna. Donec vel ante ac lacus commodo bibendum facilisis non ex. In tortor quam, commodo vel posuere vel, iaculis in quam. Nam aliquam ligula nunc, sit amet pulvinar nibh commodo non. Aliquam erat volutpat.\n\nAliquam sit amet egestas enim, et varius nibh. Pellentesque consectetur molestie lacus, ut tempor tortor pretium sit amet. Praesent ac dignissim felis, quis elementum tortor. Cras a malesuada ipsum. Mauris vitae tristique odio. Ut id ipsum maximus, posuere neque ut, rhoncus mauris. Fusce elit tortor, mattis et scelerisque nec, vestibulum vitae risus. In quis accumsan arcu. Sed sed velit leo.\n\nVivamus vulputate lorem at posuere interdum. Vivamus fermentum vitae risus consectetur placerat. Morbi lobortis sed mauris sed eleifend. Morbi non sapien a elit semper faucibus non vitae sapien. Praesent sagittis porttitor lacus pulvinar hendrerit. Nullam a lacus mi. Sed in pulvinar diam. Vivamus id egestas nulla, vitae euismod ipsum.",
    "skills": "Web",
    "no_positions": "1",
    "job_position": "Developer",
    "gender_spec": "Male",
    "job_time": "job_time",
    "experience": "1 Year",
    "city": "Lahore",
    "status": "approve",
    "post_date": "2017-04-08 16:01:28"
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "company_id": "1",
    "job_title": "Full Stack Php Developer",
    "descr": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed quis magna non arcu cursus pharetra et posuere est. Curabitur nibh neque, euismod eget felis sed, gravida cursus risus. Praesent mattis rutrum posuere. Integer eget odio mauris. Fusce luctus, ex nec lobortis vestibulum, arcu arcu suscipit magna, at gravida erat lorem sit amet est. Duis eget ante non ante blandit scelerisque vel et nunc. Nullam a nisl tincidunt, congue risus in, scelerisque ipsum. Phasellus fermentum, nibh id convallis varius, orci urna feugiat velit, in imperdiet dolor nulla non velit. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Phasellus vel quam ex. Morbi a nibh efficitur, viverra odio eget, feugiat massa. Etiam rhoncus, metus at lobortis dapibus, quam mi auctor odio, a vestibulum ante justo pellentesque urna. Donec vel ante ac lacus commodo bibendum facilisis non ex. In tortor quam, commodo vel posuere vel, iaculis in quam. Nam aliquam ligula nunc, sit amet pulvinar nibh commodo non. Aliquam erat volutpat.\n\nAliquam sit amet egestas enim, et varius nibh. Pellentesque consectetur molestie lacus, ut tempor tortor pretium sit amet. Praesent ac dignissim felis, quis elementum tortor. Cras a malesuada ipsum. Mauris vitae tristique odio. Ut id ipsum maximus, posuere neque ut, rhoncus mauris. Fusce elit tortor, mattis et scelerisque nec, vestibulum vitae risus. In quis accumsan arcu. Sed sed velit leo.\n\nVivamus vulputate lorem at posuere interdum. Vivamus fermentum vitae risus consectetur placerat. Morbi lobortis sed mauris sed eleifend. Morbi non sapien a elit semper faucibus non vitae sapien. Praesent sagittis porttitor lacus pulvinar hendrerit. Nullam a lacus mi. Sed in pulvinar diam. Vivamus id egestas nulla, vitae euismod ipsum.",
    "skills": "Web",
    "no_positions": "3",
    "job_position": "Developer",
    "gender_spec": "Male",
    "job_time": "job_time",
    "experience": "1 Year",
    "city": "Delhi",
    "status": "approve",
    "post_date": "2017-04-08 20:24:02"
  }];
});
```

html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.6/angular.min.js" ></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  <div ng-repeat="f in alljobs">
    <input type='checkbox' ng-model='f.included'> {{f.city}}
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="f in alljobs | filter:{included:true}">{{f.city}}</li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: by `filter:{included:true}` you are showing items with property `include` which's value is true. there is nothing about the previous ng-repeat(it's just change alljobs's included to be true).

Comment: how to solve this issue?

Comment: can't send any message don't know why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By `filter:{included:true}`, you are filtering items with property `included` with value `true`, and since you are adding `included:true` dynamically to `alljobs`, if you want to show all the data, you have to change all of your data with `included:true` and this will lead to all checkboxes to be checked.

There is another option which is build a custom filter to handle all these things.
and transform to the filter with an array of cities checked.

```
app.filter("sampleFilter", function() {
  return function(input, options) {
    if(!input) return [];
    if(!options || options.length === 0) return input;

    return input.filter(function(item) {
      for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        if (item.city.indexOf(options[i]) > -1) {    // filter city property only, you can add more.
          return true;
        };
      };
      return false;
    });
  }
});
```

refer the below example.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.filter("sampleFilter", function() {
  return function(input, options) {
    if(!input) return [];
    if(!options || options.length === 0) return input;
    
    return input.filter(function(item) {
      for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        if (item.city.indexOf(options[i]) > -1) {
          return true;
        };
      };
      return false;
    });
  }
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.conditions = [];
  $scope.alljobs = [{
    "id": "1",
    "company_id": "1",
    "job_title": "Full Stack ngularJs Developer",
    "descr": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed quis magna non arcu cursus pharetra et posuere est. Curabitur nibh neque, euismod eget felis sed, gravida cursus risus. Praesent mattis rutrum posuere. Integer eget odio mauris. Fusce luctus, ex nec lobortis vestibulum, arcu arcu suscipit magna, at gravida erat lorem sit amet est. Duis eget ante non ante blandit scelerisque vel et nunc. Nullam a nisl tincidunt, congue risus in, scelerisque ipsum. Phasellus fermentum, nibh id convallis varius, orci urna feugiat velit, in imperdiet dolor nulla non velit. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Phasellus vel quam ex. Morbi a nibh efficitur, viverra odio eget, feugiat massa. Etiam rhoncus, metus at lobortis dapibus, quam mi auctor odio, a vestibulum ante justo pellentesque urna. Donec vel ante ac lacus commodo bibendum facilisis non ex. In tortor quam, commodo vel posuere vel, iaculis in quam. Nam aliquam ligula nunc, sit amet pulvinar nibh commodo non. Aliquam erat volutpat.\n\nAliquam sit amet egestas enim, et varius nibh. Pellentesque consectetur molestie lacus, ut tempor tortor pretium sit amet. Praesent ac dignissim felis, quis elementum tortor. Cras a malesuada ipsum. Mauris vitae tristique odio. Ut id ipsum maximus, posuere neque ut, rhoncus mauris. Fusce elit tortor, mattis et scelerisque nec, vestibulum vitae risus. In quis accumsan arcu. Sed sed velit leo.\n\nVivamus vulputate lorem at posuere interdum. Vivamus fermentum vitae risus consectetur placerat. Morbi lobortis sed mauris sed eleifend. Morbi non sapien a elit semper faucibus non vitae sapien. Praesent sagittis porttitor lacus pulvinar hendrerit. Nullam a lacus mi. Sed in pulvinar diam. Vivamus id egestas nulla, vitae euismod ipsum.",
    "skills": "Web",
    "no_positions": "1",
    "job_position": "Developer",
    "gender_spec": "Male",
    "job_time": "job_time",
    "experience": "1 Year",
    "city": "Lahore",
    "status": "approve",
    "post_date": "2017-04-08 16:01:28"
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "company_id": "1",
    "job_title": "Full Stack Php Developer",
    "descr": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed quis magna non arcu cursus pharetra et posuere est. Curabitur nibh neque, euismod eget felis sed, gravida cursus risus. Praesent mattis rutrum posuere. Integer eget odio mauris. Fusce luctus, ex nec lobortis vestibulum, arcu arcu suscipit magna, at gravida erat lorem sit amet est. Duis eget ante non ante blandit scelerisque vel et nunc. Nullam a nisl tincidunt, congue risus in, scelerisque ipsum. Phasellus fermentum, nibh id convallis varius, orci urna feugiat velit, in imperdiet dolor nulla non velit. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Phasellus vel quam ex. Morbi a nibh efficitur, viverra odio eget, feugiat massa. Etiam rhoncus, metus at lobortis dapibus, quam mi auctor odio, a vestibulum ante justo pellentesque urna. Donec vel ante ac lacus commodo bibendum facilisis non ex. In tortor quam, commodo vel posuere vel, iaculis in quam. Nam aliquam ligula nunc, sit amet pulvinar nibh commodo non. Aliquam erat volutpat.\n\nAliquam sit amet egestas enim, et varius nibh. Pellentesque consectetur molestie lacus, ut tempor tortor pretium sit amet. Praesent ac dignissim felis, quis elementum tortor. Cras a malesuada ipsum. Mauris vitae tristique odio. Ut id ipsum maximus, posuere neque ut, rhoncus mauris. Fusce elit tortor, mattis et scelerisque nec, vestibulum vitae risus. In quis accumsan arcu. Sed sed velit leo.\n\nVivamus vulputate lorem at posuere interdum. Vivamus fermentum vitae risus consectetur placerat. Morbi lobortis sed mauris sed eleifend. Morbi non sapien a elit semper faucibus non vitae sapien. Praesent sagittis porttitor lacus pulvinar hendrerit. Nullam a lacus mi. Sed in pulvinar diam. Vivamus id egestas nulla, vitae euismod ipsum.",
    "skills": "Web",
    "no_positions": "3",
    "job_position": "Developer",
    "gender_spec": "Male",
    "job_time": "job_time",
    "experience": "1 Year",
    "city": "Delhi",
    "status": "approve",
    "post_date": "2017-04-08 20:24:02"
  }];
  
  $scope.clickEvt = function(e, data) {
    if (e.target.checked) {
      $scope.conditions.push(data.city);
    } else {
      $scope.conditions.splice($scope.conditions.indexOf(data.city), 1);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  <div ng-repeat="f in alljobs">
    <input type='checkbox' ng-click="clickEvt($event, f)"> {{f.city}}
  </div>
  Conditions: {{conditions}}
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="f in alljobs | sampleFilter: conditions">{{f.city}}</li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```